# iOS: How to distinguish between iPhone mode and iPad mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm building an universal iOS app and some config variables have different value between iPhone mode and iPad mode. Please notice that I said the **Mode** word.

As I know, users could install an iPhone app in iPad from AppStore, so there is something confused to me about the following code:

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([deviceType rangeOfString:@"iPad" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
{
    fCurrentDeviceIsiPad = YES;
    // ...
}
else // iPhone? iPod? 
{
    fCurrentDeviceIsiPad = NO;
    // ...
}
```

If user install & run the iPhone version app in iPad, the fCurrentDeviceIsiPad will be YES (I tested the result with debugging it in my iPad for iPhone version, certainly, I'd changed the deployment device as "iPhone" only first).

So, my question is how could I distinguish the app **mode** without taking the device type as consideration?

[Someone](http://cduu.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/differentiate-between-iphone-and-simulator/) posted something about the OS macros, I've tried them in my app.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  // iPhone specific code
  #error A
#elif TARGET_OS_IPAD
  // iPad specific code
  #error B
#else
  // Unknown target
  #error C
#endif
```

This didn't hit my point, either. I switched the debug device to iPhone simulator and iPad simulator, all the compile errors are hit on error A. Did I misunderstand the meaning of these macros?

One more question, this will be the first time I submit an iOS to AppStore and it's an universal app. For the submit process, is it standalone process for uploading iPhone version binary and iPad version binary? You may get my new point: if the answer is yes, it's ok for me to build two versions manually with my custom-macros.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Problem solved!

The code `[UIDevice currentDevice].model` is NOT the same with the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`, the former one always returns the real device type, the latter one is the current running app mode/version.

Comment: Macro are evaluated at compile time. Unless you have two separate targets in Xcode for ipad and iphone, it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BOOL isIpad() {
    return UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
}
```

Comment: It seems I posted a duplicated question, I found this code before but I thought this function is almost the same with comparing the model value of device just like the above code.
Anyway, I've tried this and it works: the return value is NO when I run the iPhone version app in my iPad.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create an NSObject file and name it Common. Delete the .m and delete all the code written in Common.h
Import the Common.h file in .pch file
Put this is the Common.h file
And then you can use it throughout your app.

```
#define IS_IPHONE (!IS_IPAD)
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Thanks.